# Using variables in Javascript Open Function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I have what is probably a pretty basic question. I have some tools tips and want to open them with a click. I create a Javascript call on the click. I can pas the element ID I want to open, but I don't know how to get it to work in the Open call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function opentip(tipID) {
//alert(tipID);
$(#tipID).tooltipster('open');
}
</script>
```

Comment: `'#' + tipID` should work

Comment: '#' + tipID worked! Thanks! I'm passing the ID because I want to open different points on the map.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary the function `opentip(tipID)` to bind the mouse click. I will give you  an genereic exemple. You have to import Tooltipster's CSS and JS, and jQuery, so the code will be:

```
<span class="tooltip" title="Tooltip content!">Target tag</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            trigger: 'click'
        });
    });
</script>
```

When clicl on "Target tag" will appear an tooltip with "Tooltip content!" inside.

The `$(document).ready(function() {});` is important to be sure that when the script runs, the browser have already the DOM ready, so the script can find the HTML elements.

Answer (score -1):

You are using JQuery syntax. Insert `JQuery` plugin and add single quotes in your syntax `$('#'+tipID).tooltipster('open');` and add inside `document.ready`

```js
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function opentip(tipID) {
                 //alert(tipID);
                $('#'+tipID).tooltipster('open');
               }
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $() function, strings have to be surrounded by ' or ".

Comment: But doesn't this assume that the actual ID of the element is "tipID"? You're not using the `tipID` variable passed into the function.

Comment: tipID deve ser para identificar qual foi clicado e abrir a tooltip somente daquele, mas não é bem assim que esse script funciona. Mas `$('#tipID').tooltipster('open');` deve ser algo como `$('#'+tipID).tooltipster('open');`

Comment: Sorry about the portuguese comment, i thouth that i'm Stack Overflow Portuguese